# Is there Modern UI equivalent for Asset Picker?

Tags: spfx, modern-experience, modern-pages, iframe, path

I have a SharePoint Framework application and I'm trying to get a Site page link or document link and paste it into my text editor, which is embedded into my spfx app.

Is there any way to return selected file path back from **/_layouts/15/AssetPortalBrowser.aspx** iframe to SPFx web part from where that iframe was called?

Specifically speaking, SP 2010-2013 has SP.UI.ModalDialog's **dialogReturnValueCallback** option. Does SPO has some equivalent for that?
Any ideas would be great. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this pnp spfx control. It provides a file picker for the modern UI
https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/FilePicker/